# Adding <UL> tag

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am having trouble in adding li tags inside ul tags in for loop

Here is my json :

```
{
 "pageArr": [
    {"curve_main": "Curve-1",
      "curve_sub": [
        {"curve_name": "A-1",
         "curve_rel": [
            "Conrway-1",
            "Conrway-2",
            "Conrway-3",
            "Conrway-4",
            "Conrway-5",
            "Conrway-6"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my js for loop code :

```
    for (i = 0; i < data.pageArr.length; i++) {
    container.append("<h1>" + data.pageArr[i].curve_main + "</h1>");

            for (x = 0; x < data.pageArr[i].curve_sub.length; x++) {
                container.append("<h2>" + data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_name + "</h2>");
                            for (y = 0; y < data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_rel.length; y++) {
                                container.append("<li>" + data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_rel[y] + "</li>");
                            }
            }
    }

});
```

});

I am trying to render "curve_rel" Array into in "li" tags and wrap them in "ul" tags . I have managed to render them in li tags, how can I wrap them in `<ul>`.

The forloop I have now is rendering into

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Curve-1</h1>
<h2>A-1</h2>
<li>Conrway-1</li>
<li>Conrway-2</li>
<li>Conrway-3</li>
<li>Conrway-4</li>
<li>Conrway-5</li>
<li>Conrway-6</li>
</div>
```

Thanks 
Justin

Answer (score 0):

You could check the index to figure out when to append the `ul` tag.

If the index is 0, add the opening `<ul>`. If the index is equal to the (length + 1) of the array (length doesn't start from 0 like your loop does), then add the closing `</ul>`

From within your `for` loop:

```
container.append("<h2>" + data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_name + "</h2>");
if (x === 0) {
  container.append('<ul>');
}

// add your <li> tags here

if (x + 1 === data.pageArr[i].curve_sub.length) {
  container.append('</ul>');
}
```

You could avoid the `+ 1` calculation by changing your `for` loop to:

`for (x = 1; x <= data.pageArr[i].curve_sub.length; ++x)`

In that instance, the code would be:

```
container.append("<h2>" + data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_name + "</h2>");
if (x === 1) {
  container.append('<ul>');
}

// add your <li> tags here

if (x === data.pageArr[i].curve_sub.length) {
  container.append('</ul>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just want to add strings to your container, then you can just append your ul before & after your inner loop:

```
for (x = 0; x < data.pageArr[i].curve_sub.length; x++) {
            container.append("<h2>" + data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_name + "</h2>");
            container.append('<ul>');
                        for (y = 0; y < data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_rel.length; y++) {
                            container.append("<li>" + data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_rel[y] + "</li>");
                        }
            container.append('</ul>');
        }
```

However, none of this code will actually add anything to the DOM.  If you want to do that, then you need to use document.createElement().  Something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.pageArr.length; i++) {
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    container.append(h1);
    h1.append(data.pageArr[i].curve_main);

    for (x = 0; x < data.pageArr[i].curve_sub.length; x++) {
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        container.append(h2);
        h2.append(data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_name);

        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        container.append(ul);
        for (y = 0; y < data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_rel.length; y++) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.append(data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_rel[y]);
            ul.append(li);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Thanks Lance 
just changed pageArr[i]  to data.pageArr[i]

Answer (score -1):

Just escape the quotes

```
container.append("<li>\"" + data.pageArr[i].curve_sub[x].curve_rel[y] + "\"</li>");
```